# ActionBarDrawerToggle v7 or v4?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying use ActionBarDrawerToggle in my CustomDrawerLayout. When I try import `import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;` it is deprecated. When I try import `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;` the constructor not accept five arguments and the icon not changed in ActionBar. My question is I should use v4 deprecated or v7 with four arguments ?

here.

**v4**

```
/**v4 works with 5 arguments in constructor and change icon ActionBar but it's deprecated*/
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;

//ActionBarDrawerToggle deprecated
tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
```

**v7**

```
/**v7 works with 4 arguments in constructor and not change icon of ActionBar*/
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;

tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
```

**CustomDrawerLayout**

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;

    private List<ItensListView> fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar)));
        init();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            selectedItem(0);
        }       
    }

    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        configItensListView();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);               
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);

        tl = tlf = getTitle();

    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }




    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }

    /** necessario */
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         FragmentTransaction ft;
         Fragment frag;

         if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_chat){
             frag = new HelloBubblesActivity();
             ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag, "HelloBubblesActivity");
             ft.addToBackStack("back");
             ft.commit();
         }

         if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }


     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(lv);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: With the current `ActionBarActivity`, I think your only choice is the `v7` version of `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In v7 constructor, you should pass this as parameters :

```
new ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

While the v4 constructor is

```
new ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int drawerImageRes, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

I think in you v7 constructor you kept the drawerImageRes as the third parameter (ic_launcher).

Try with this instead :

```
new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
```